# Запрет на доступ к файлам

Tags: .htaccess, файлы

Доброго времени суток! Как сделать, чтобы у меня на сайте был доступ только к `index.php`? то-есть через адресную строку нельзя было например открыть `config.txt`

Comment: Права поменять? Или я чего-то не понял? Все запросы через .htaccess можно на index.php слать.

Comment: RewriteRule ^config.txt$ - [F]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^config.txt$ - [F]
```

Как вариант.